# Returning true false from Promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, redux, axios

I have a login form in React Js which submits user details on button click.

What I am trying to get is when user submit details an API of user data is called which returns a list of the user. Then when The code gets user list I check if the user is present in the list or not.

I am stuck after the result has come.
I want to `return true or false` to `setstate` of Error but instead I get undefined.

This is the function which runs

```js
let handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let result;
    result = validateLogin(formDetails.name, formDetails.password);

    console.log("------------", result); //getting undefined instead of True or false 

}
```

**ValidateLogin:**

```js
let validateLogin = async (email, password) => {
    const response = await axios.get('https://fakestoreapi.com/users');
    if (response) {
        const k = response.data.find(user => {
            return user.email === email && user.password === password
        })
        if (k) {
  
            return true
        } else {
           
            return false
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `result = await validateLogin(formDetails.name, formDetails.password);`

Comment: Tried it but instead got an error `Parsing error: 'await' is only allowed within async functions`

Comment: That says it all, right? Make your function `async`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`validateLogin` is async function, so you should make `handleSubmit` as async function and resolve the `validateLogin` to get the result.

```js
let handleSubmit = async e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let result = await validateLogin(formDetails.name, formDetails.password);

  console.log('------------', result); //getting undefined instead of True or false
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In Validate Login File,
`const response = await axios.get('https://fakestoreapi.com/users');`
is not executing. And therefore there is no return from Validate Login

`if(response)`
`{`

```
    `...`
```

`} else{`

```
    `return something;`
```

`}`

Try to return something with else.